# AutoFixture with NUnit and AutoData throws TargetParameterCountException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, autofixture

In my unit test project I have installed AutoFixture (v3.40.0), NUnit (v2.6.4.) and AutoFixtrue.NUnit2(v3.39.0).
I'm using AutoData attribute on one of the dummy test cases

```
[Test, AutoData]
public void IntroductoryTest(
    int expectedNumber)
{               

}
```

, but when running the test I get the

```
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException : Parameter count mismatch.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at NUnit.Core.Reflect.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object fixture, Object[] args)
   at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestMethod()
   at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestCase(TestResult testResult)
```

Is there anything I haven't installed or I'm missing?

Comment: Do you need *both* NUnit and NUnit2? This might be causing that issue.

Comment: FWIW, the add-in model of NUnit 2 is causing all sorts of problems, so if you have any choice at all, consider using xUnit.net instead, where *AutoFixture.XUnit2* and *AutoFixture.Xunit* have worked flawlessly for years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That exception is caused by NUnit not loading the AutoFixture [add-in](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunitAddins&r=2.4) *at runtime* so the test parameters don't get any arguments.

The reason is that [AutoFixture.NUnit2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.NUnit2/) is compiled against version [2.6.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/2.6.2) so if you want to use it with [2.6.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/2.6.4) you'll have to add the following [assembly binding redirects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) to the configuration file of your test project:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                name="nunit.core.interfaces" 
                publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77"
                culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect
                oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.4.14350"
                newVersion="2.6.4.14350" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                name="nunit.core"
                publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77"
                culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect
                oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.4.14350"
                newVersion="2.6.4.14350" />
          </dependentAssembly>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Note that the version of NUnit you need to *redirect to* is the one used by the *test runner*, which could be different than the version used during compilation.

So, while you might be compiling your tests against version [2.6.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/2.6.4), if your test runner uses version [2.6.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/2.6.3), then you need to redirect to [2.6.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/2.6.3) instead:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                name="nunit.core.interfaces" 
                publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77"
                culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect
                oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.3.13283"
                newVersion="2.6.3.13283" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                name="nunit.core"
                publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77"
                culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect
                oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.3.13283"
                newVersion="2.6.3.13283" />
          </dependentAssembly>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I've just added `<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.core.interfaces" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.3.13283" newVersion="2.6.3.13283" />
      </dependentAssembly>` in App.config and that was enough
You can edit your answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: That binding redirect is for NUnit 2.6.3. In the question you mentioned NUnit 2.6.4. Which version are you using?